# How to differentiate Databases in ASP.Net Core 2.1 Application based on Enviroment?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am building this ASP.Net Core MVC Application. Thing is I want to keep three different environments for my Databases, Like Development, Sandbox & Production. Is there any way I can mention that in my app setting file or will I need to manually specify in the deployment like I normally do? Like I am deploying a self-contained application on Elastic Beanstalk & for now, I have edited the appsettings.json file with the required database but that is just like one DB at a time.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server = tcp:<Remote DB Server>,1433; Database = <DB>; User Id = <DB Username>; Password = <DB PASS>;"
```

TL:DR; Can I have multiple Connection strings as per the enviroment in my appsettings.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [configuration by environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configuration-by-environment) chapter of the official documentation, you have a few options for this:

> To load configuration by environment, we recommend:
>
> - *appsettings* files (`appsettings.<>.json`). See [Configuration: File configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#file-configuration-provider).
> - environment variables (set on each system where the app is hosted). See Configuration: [File configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#file-configuration-provider) and [Safe storage of app secrets in development: Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1#environment-variables).
> - Secret Manager (in the Development environment only). See [Safe storage of app secrets in development in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

The first option is a very common solution for environment-specific configuration and simply involves in additional `appsettings.json` files that include the environment name in the file name. The default templates already come with a `appsettings.Development.json` file that is only loaded for the `Development` environment. Similarly, you could create a `appsettings.Sandbox.json` and a `appsettings.Production.json` file that are loaded with the `Sandbox` and `Production` environment respectively.

The configuration files are loaded *in addition* to the normal `appsettings.json` file, so you can use that to specify general defaults and only overwrite environment-specific things in the environment-specific `appsettings.<Environment>.json` files.

Note that you should always try to avoid putting production secrets in files, especially those that are committed to source control. For those, you can also use environment variables to overwrite specific values. For example, an environment variable `ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection` could contain the connection string for your application and would overwrite what is configured in one of the *appsettings* files.